# Clang error for os_log timeval format

Tags: ios, objective-c, logging, clang

I am using Apple's [Unified Logging](https://developer.apple.com/reference/os/logging?language=objc) for the first time, and have had some success. However, I can't get it to work with the suggested `%{timeval}.*P` custom format specifier.

My first attempt was something like:

```
struct timeval some_time;
// ... populate `some_time` 
os_log_info(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "a thing happened at %{timeval}.*P", some_time);
```

But clang reports an error: `field precision should have type 'int', but argument has type 'struct timeval'`.

I believe the problem is that clang doesn't doesn't understand the `os_log` formatting rules, and if I could work out how to have clang suppress the error via `clang diagnostic push` etc, I would. It does appear that the underlying macro `OS_LOG_CALL_WITH_FORMAT` seems to make an attempt to do that, without luck.

Am I misusing the `timeval` format specifier?

This is with Xcode 8.3.1, I haven't tried earlier versions of Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

The `timeval` format specifier is correct as according to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/os/logging?language=objc). Apparently Clang is not yet aware of these new format strings as of Xcode 8.3.2. Deactivating it via `#clang diagnostic ignored "-Wformat"` would be a futile attempt.

[image: Format specifier documentation]

Apparently there is no solution to this – in the mean time avoid using these new fancy format specifiers. Specifically, avoid the format strings that ends with a `.*P`. However the `d` formats seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

Working code

```
os_log_info(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "a thing happened at %{timeval}.16P", &some_time);
```

OR

```
os_log_info(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "a thing happened at %{timeval}.*P", (int)sizeof(some_time), &some_time);
```

The problem here is that wildcard (*) in format definition stands for int. So in fact %{timeval}.*P accepts 2 arguments: int and a pointer to timeval struct.

Unfortunately, this is very badly documented and even [Apple Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Logging/Introduction/Intro.html) of os_log usage doesn't have examples of this.

So far the best way to see examples is to look into tests in LLVM source code.
[format-strings-oslog.m](https://reviews.llvm.org/diffusion/L/browse/cfe/trunk/test/SemaObjC/format-strings-oslog.m)

```
__builtin_os_log_format(buf, "%d", i);
__builtin_os_log_format(buf, "%P", p); // expected-warning {{using '%P' format specifier without precision}}
__builtin_os_log_format(buf, "%.10P", p);
__builtin_os_log_format(buf, "%.*P", p); // expected-warning {{field precision should have type 'int', but argument has type 'void *'}}
__builtin_os_log_format(buf, "%.*P", i, p);
__builtin_os_log_format(buf, "%.*P", i, i); // expected-warning {{format specifies type 'void *' but the argument has type 'int'}}
```